# Using Knockout.js to bind to a data-icon

Tags: css, knockout.js, icons, font-face

I've got a section in my app where I'd like to display a dynamic icon that's generated via an icon font-face. Here's the markup I'm attempting to use (based on a pattern I've seen in multiple places for using an icon font):

```
<span data-bind="attr: {'data-icon': iconCode}"></span>
```

And here's the relevant CSS that I apply to that :

```
[data-icon]:before {
    font-family: 'Icons';
    content: attr(data-icon);
}
```

When I set the `iconCode` observable to the code representing the icon I want (i.e., `"&#xe000"` with a semicolon at the end that I've left off here), it displays the text string and doesn't convert it into a character. If I manually edit the `data-icon` attribute of the tag using dev tools, it'll show the icon correctly, so I know there's nothing wrong with my markup or CSS.

I assume there's got to be something preventing the browser from being able to handle a dynamically inserted character like this. I'm using a small enough set of icons that it wouldn't be *that* big of a deal to create a CSS class for each and apply the class name dynamically, but I'd rather have a pattern that affords me the flexibility of using any character I'd like. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the DOM to convert the HTML escape sequence into an actual character:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.iconCode = ko.observable();

    self.iconCodeChar = ko.computed(function () {
        var div = document.createElement("DIV");
        div.innerHTML = self.iconCode();
        return div.textContent || div.innerText;
    });
}
```

and bind to the computed observable:

```
<span data-bind="attr: {'data-icon': iconCodeChar}"></span>
```

Beware of the potential script injection vulnerability through the use of `.innerHTML`. Some sort of input value checking might be necessary.

Comment: Thanks! I used a slightly different approach, but the idea to inject the escape sequence into the DOM was spot on. In my case, I already had a custom binding I was using to set the inner HTML of an element, so I just used that and passed it the escape sequence. Works like a charm!

Comment: @kgoggin Good to hear! Thanks for the feedback, too.